# Parsing PHP soap responses

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

I am getting soap response from Bluegrace shipping,Can anyone please help me to extract particular data from simpleXMLLoadElement object. I am creating custom shipping module for Magento with Bluegrace shipping, I will share my module if anyone needed this.

Here is my code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);

 $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

$soap = $xml->children($ns['soap']);

foreach ($soap->children($ns['Quote']) as $item)

{

print  $item->children($ns['Total']).'<br>';


}
```

It will print complete string of response without tags

Below is the response that i am getting

```
<StatusCode>1</StatusCode>

<StatusMessage>StatusMessage1</StatusMessage>

<Quotes>

  <Quote>

    <Currency>NcName1</Currency>

    <QuoteDate>QuoteDate1</QuoteDate>

    <FreightTotal>1</FreightTotal>

    <ServicesTotal>1</ServicesTotal>

    <Total>1</Total>

    <CarrierName>NcName1</CarrierName>


  </Quote>

</Quotes>
```

Comment: "extract particular data" what data you want to extract?